# Motobecane 1970's version

Tags: tire, innertube

I have a 1970's Motobecane bicycle with 27x1 tires. I need new tires and tubes. What would be the best size to fit, as I cannot find an exact match?

Comment: Are the tires tubular or clincher?

Comment: I would suggest you buy 27x1 tires.  It may be that the best local retailers have is 27x7/8 or 27x1-1/8, but those should be fine.